# Python Watchdog - incorrect events (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: python-3.x, python-watchdog

I am trying to use `python watchdog` to check for modifications to files and then parse the modified file. The problem I have is that it seems Visual Studio creates a separate file when modifying a file then when saving the file it swaps the old file and the new file out which creates an `on_moved` event from watchdog instead of the desired event `on_modified`.

**My question is if there is a way to disable this feature in *visual studio* (preferably a per project bases setting)?**

This is a known problem in Vim which is documented on watchdogs API and notes to turn off this feature to obtain the desired behaviour. This is why I assume you might be able to do the same in visual studio 2017.